# Why is are my rows not being written to the CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

With the code below the CSV file aaab.csv is created but nothing is written to it. The print(row) gives me the correct information. What am I doing wrong? I have tried writer.close() but that gives me an error.

```
import csv
from csv import writer
from csv import reader
dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}
duplist = []
notinlist2 = []
counta = 0
countb = 0
with open('/Users/list2.csv') as file_handler:
    reader = csv.reader(file_handler)
    next(reader, None) # skip header
    for row in reader:
        key = row[1]
        counta += 1
        #print(key)
        if key in dict1.keys():
            duplist.append(key)
            
        else:
            dict1[row[1]] = counta


reader = csv.reader(open('/Users/list1.csv','r'))
writer = csv.writer(open('/Users/aaab.csv', 'w',encoding='UTF8'))
next(reader, None) # skip header
headers = ['MVA','REG','No']
writer.writerow(headers)
for row in reader:
    key = row[1]
    
    if key in dict1.keys():
        a = dict1.get(row[1])
        countb += 1
        row.append(a)
        writer.writerow(row)
        print(row)
        
                
    else:
        notinlist2.append(key)
        writer.writerow(row)
        print(row)

    
print(len(dict1))
print(duplist)
print(notinlist2)
print(countb)
```

Here is a sample CSV

```
MVA    ,REG 
8144802,BK36HNGP 
5296130,BN33KWGP 
3254005,BT50XBGP
```

Comment: Please provide a sample CSV so your code can be tested properly.

Comment: The CSV files look like this: MVA,REG
8144802,BK36HNGP
5296130,BN33KWGP
3254005,BT50XBGP There are eleven lines in each file excluding the headers.

Comment: I would suggest you close the files at the end, or much better, use a `with open()...` statement. The close needs to be on the `open()` not the CSV writer.

Comment: @MartinEvans changing to with open() has done the trick. Thanks.